# How to freehand draw a polyline onto Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm creating a mobile walking web app using leaflet.  I'd like the user to add a path, or polyline, between two markers, which may or may not follow the road.  I'd like them to be able to freehand draw a polyline by dragging their finger or mouse, across the map.  When they lift, the polyline will render with its "elbows" for editing.

I've looked at a few plugins:

- The Leaflet.draw only works by clicking points on the map, then it fills in
  with a straight line. I'd really like the user to draw a curvy line freehand on their mobile device, which is more intuitive.
- leaflet-freedraw only draws polygons. If it could be altered to only
  draw polylines it looks exactly what I'm looking for.  Not sure if it can be used on mobile devices, however.
- L.pather https://github.com/Wildhoney/L.Pather looks closer to what I want, but I can't figure out how to
  download and use it, because I use npm and not bower. Sorry, I'm still newbie about that stuff.

If anybody can point me in the right direction I'd be much appreciative.  I'm looking for an existing library, preferably, but willing to dig in and customize others, if it's possible.

Comment: You can use bower to install the pather library, or just copy paste the code here to a js file you create https://github.com/Wildhoney/L.Pather/blob/master/dist/pather.js

Comment: Did u find a way to use in yours Single File Components on vue?